# Problem comparing Ising model with Mean Field Theory

Tags: ising-model

After implementing the Metropolis algorithm for the Ising model, I tried comparing my values with the MFT predictions. Shouldn't the phase change occur at T/Tc? I would guess that my mistake is in calculating the temperature for each case. I have set the system so that temperature is dimensionless though I believe I have set the β - T/Tc connection incorrectly.

Any advice?

[image: Alignment obviously incorrect.]

Comment: If yours is a 2d Ising model, what is the form of your Tc? Beta?

Answer (score 1):

First, what Ising model do you use? Is it a 3-dimensional nearest-neighbor Ising model for a simple cubic lattice? Then the numerical value of the critical temperature is well-known (see, e.g., K. Binder, E. Luijten / Physics Reports 344 (2001) 179-253), and this is the value you should compare your results with. Why do you think MFT provides good predictions for this model?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to ask if there is a nice way to easily deduce if MFT of a given model will give good predictions, or you need to perform detailed analysis everytime, say by looking at the values of critical exponents? Thanks.

Comment: @BruceLee:  Difficult to say. Obviously, that depends on what you need. In 3d, MFT works better when the radius of interaction is large.

Comment: I see. By the way when you increase the radius of interaction, I believe you are making your model tailor-made for MFT, as by definition you are including the long-wavelength modes. So for a given model in question, if you show that short-distant modes are averaged out in the calculation of some physical observable, what you get will be in good agreement with MFT calculations. Is that correct?

Comment: @BruceLee:  Not sure - I have not worked in the area of statistical physics for many years.